# Extract OpenVMS backup on Linux

Tags: openvms

I have a backup file created on an OpenVMS server. How can I extract the backup on a Linux machine?

The backup was created using the `backup` command. The backup stores the `.bak`. file on a Linux server over an NFS share.

I tried [vmsbackup](http://labs.hoffmanlabs.com/node/1338) but it is complaining about the block size being wrong.

`Snark: Invalid block size - expected: 32256 got: 32256`

I also tried [Tony Bell's Software](http://www.megatony.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/tools/vmsbackup/index.htm) but it does not put the files in directories (it makes the file name with the full path in the file name).

Comment: How was the backup created?

Comment: @MichaelHampton - yeah good point. I edited a bit.